# Find the order of a defined subgroup of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

For a fixed $n\geq 3$, Prove $H=\{\alpha \in S_n | \alpha(3)=3$ and $\alpha(2) =2\}$ is a subgroup of $S_n$. Find the order of H.

I have already proved that $H$ is a subgroup of $S_n$.

I know the order of $S_n = n!$. Would a subgroup of $S_n$ have the same order? Or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is a finite group, the only subgroup of $G$ with the same order is $G$ itself.

The subgroup $H$ is basically $S_{n-2}$. Therefore, its order is $(n-2)!$.

Comment: Why is the order of H $S_{n-2}$?

Comment: You want to show that $H \cong S_{n - 2}$, so they have the same order, which is $(n - 2)!$

Comment: Because, if $\sigma\in H$, you have $n-2$ choices for $\sigma(1)$, $n-3$ choices for $\sigma(4)$, $n-4$ choices for $\sigma(5)$, …, and $1$ choice for $\sigma(n)$. Therefore, there are $(n-2)\times(n-3)\times\cdots\times1=(n-2)!$ elements in $H$. And note that what I wrote was that $H$ is basically $S_{n-2}$, not that the order of $H$ is $S_{n-2}$ (the order of $H$ is a natural numbers, not a group).

Answer (score 1):

Note $H$ consists of all permutations on the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ that fix $3$ and $2$. For if $f\in H$, then $f(3)=3$ and $f(2)=2$. The rest $(n-2)$ [other than $2$ and $3$] elements can be mapped (by $f$) in $(n-2)!$ ways. Thus $|H|=(n-2)!$.